# How to transpose date row values into columns headers, and introduce columns for dates NOT in the input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to:

1. Transpose a list of dates into columns
2. Introduce columns for dates not explicitly in the data (e.g. in this case 03/07/2020)

I have written the following code (date format = dd/mm/yyyy):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''\
item|date
ABC1|02/07/2020
ABC1|05/07/2020
ABC1|06/07/2020
DEF2|04/07/2020
DEF2|05/07/2020'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='|', parse_dates=['date'])

df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['item'])['date']).groupby(level=[0]).max().reset_index()

print(df)
```

My code returns:

```
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| item | 02/07/2020 | 04/07/2020 | 05/07/2020 | 06/07/2020 |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ABC1 |          1 |          0 |          1 |          1 |
| DEF2 |          0 |          1 |          1 |          0 |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

This ticks off the first bit, but I have very few ideas on how to accomplish the second objective. I suspect I need to start with min and max dates from input, then build the column list from that.

Unfortunately, I don't where to start with that.

The desired outputs are as follows (notice there's a column for 3rd July):

```
**Matrix 1**
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| item | 02/07/2020 | 03/07/2020 | 04/07/2020 | 05/07/2020 | 06/07/2020 |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ABC1 |          1 |            |            |          1 |          1 |
| DEF2 |            |            |          1 |          1 |            |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+

**Matrix 2 (Inverse of matrix 1)**
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| item | 02/07/2020 | 03/07/2020 | 04/07/2020 | 05/07/2020 | 06/07/2020 |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ABC1 |            |          1 |          1 |            |            |
| DEF2 |          1 |          1 |            |            |          1 |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I hope this is possible and that I've provided enough information

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `reindex` as well:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, dayfirst=True)

new_range = pd.date_range(df.date.min(), df.date.max(), freq='D')

ret = pd.crosstab(df.item,df.date).reindex(new_range, fill_value=0, axis=1)
```

Another option is to use `as_freq`:

```
pd.crosstab(df.date,df.item).asfreq('D',fill_value=0).T
```

Output:

```
      2020-07-02  2020-07-03  2020-07-04  2020-07-05  2020-07-06
item                                                            
ABC1           1           0           0           1           1
DEF2           0           0           1           1           0
```

Comment: thank you very much for this - it works perfectly. Out of interest - would the approach be completely different if I had strings instead of 0s and 1s

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dayfirst` when reading the csv considering the format and then reindex with `replace` 0 with NaN if necessary:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='|', parse_dates=['date'],dayfirst=True)

dt_rng = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(),df['date'].max())

df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['item'])['date']).max(level=0)
       .reindex(dt_rng,axis=1).replace(0,np.nan).reset_index())

df2 = df1.isna().astype(int).replace(0,np.nan)
```

---

```
print('df1','\n',df1,'\n','df2','\n',df2)
    df1 
    item  2020-07-02 00:00:00  2020-07-03 00:00:00  2020-07-04 00:00:00  \
0  ABC1                  1.0                  NaN                  NaN   
1  DEF2                  NaN                  NaN                  1.0   

   2020-07-05 00:00:00  2020-07-06 00:00:00  
0                    1                  1.0  
1                    1                  NaN   
 df2 
    item  2020-07-02 00:00:00  2020-07-03 00:00:00  2020-07-04 00:00:00  \
0   NaN                  NaN                    1                  1.0   
1   NaN                  1.0                    1                  NaN   

   2020-07-05 00:00:00  2020-07-06 00:00:00  
0                  NaN                  NaN  
1                  NaN                  1.0
```